# How do I modify my sourdough rising/proofing time to account for not using enough starter?

Tags: substitutions, sourdough, sourdough-starter, proofing

This is my first time trying to bake sourdough bread after feeding a mature AP/wheat starter I got from a friend. I fed the starter a 1:1:1 mixture with AP flour and let it rise in a very warm room(~84F) for a few hours. It nearly tripled in size, then I put it in the fridge, and took it out the next morning to bake with. I let it warm up on the counter for a couple of hours before making the dough.

I didn't realize until I was scooping the starter from the jar that I did not have nearly enough for what the recipe called for. I could only use slightly over half the amount called for.

How do I account for this? I assume the yeasts and bacteria will need longer to raise the dough since there's not enough of them? Can I simply double the rise time? Do I need to double the proofing time as well? The recipe also calls for stretching and folding every 30 mins. Do I have to modify this as well?

Answer (score 2):

I bake with a sour dough starter frequently, and run into this often, mainly because of lack of planning.  When I solve for this, I first make up for the missing starter mass by adding equal parts flour and water during the initial mix of the dough.  Then, I just continue as normal.  I usually do 3 or 4 sets of stretch and fold, 30 or so minutes apart, depending on how the dough feels.  Proofing time is a different story, and highly dependent your environment, and the strength of your starter.  You probably will not need to double it, but it may take a bit longer.  After my stretch and folds, I do a bulk proof for a few hours, then shape, transfer to basket, and proof for another hour or two.  There are no clear rules or time tables here because you are working with a live product that is functioning within your specific environment.  What I've learned over time, is that I can understand how things work in my kitchen.  There are "tests" you can do to gauge proofing, such as giving your dough a poke.  If it springs back right away...let it sit a bit longer.  A slow spring-back means you are probably good to go.

I would encourage to make lots of bread.  Some of it will not look pretty. Sometime the texture will not be what you are going for. Most of it will be edible.  Over time, you will develop a feel for it, and achieve the kind of bread you have in mind.